# function_exists returns false but declaration throws error

Tags: php, oop, function, fatal-error

In PHP 5.3.6 I have a class with a method like this:

```
public function chunkText()
{
  if(!function_exists('unloadChunkText')) {
     function unloadChunkText() {
        . . .
     }
  }
  . . .
}
```

Where unloadChunkText is a helper method for chunkText.  The problem is that whenever I call $obj->chunkText() I am given this error:

> Cannot redeclare diagnostic\question\unloadChunkText()  (previously
>   declared in
>   file.php:**34**)
>   in file.php
>   on line **34**

Why isn't function_exists telling me that this function already exists?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a variable either ?

Comment: What happens if you use `function_exists('diagnostic\question\unloadChunkText')`?

Comment: @idiqual Yeah, positive it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking for the global function `unloadChunkText`, instead of the namespace-specific function `diagnostic\question\unloadChunkText`. But I suspect your approach here is flawed.

If you have a helper function for your method `chunkText()`, define it in one of two ways:

*As a closure:*

```
public function chunkText()
{
  $unloadChunkText = function () {
    // . . .
  };
  // . . .
  // Call it like $unloadChunkText()
}
```

*As a private method of the object:*

```
private function unloadChunkText ()
{
  // . . .
}

public function chunkText()
{
  // . . .
  // Call it like $this->unloadChunkText()
}
```

Defining it as a private method probably makes more sense, so you don't waste time redefining it every time you call `chunkText()`.

Answer (score 2):

Provide the scope within `function_exists()`:

```
function_exists('diagnostic\question\unloadChunkText')
```

Comment: Is there documentation that you can point me towards on this way to provide scope to `function_exists`? I was not aware this is possible!

Comment: @kavisiegel Me either! It was a shot in the dark based on the error message.. I can't find anything regarding scope in the manual for function_exists.

Comment: This answered the question I had, thank you.  Ultimately ended up modifying my code using DaveRandom's answer, though, for brevity's sake.

Comment: @beanland No hard feelings. Dave's response is definitely the way to go. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The thing with function_exists is you can't provide a scope for it. Try using `is_callable` instead, where the callback would be `array($this, 'unloadChunkText')`

Or, `method_exists` is another possibility. `method_exists($this, 'unloadChunkText')`