# function_exists returns false but can not redeclare function

Tags: php, dompdf

this is similar to [function_exists returns false but declaration throws error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316181/function-exists-returns-false-but-declaration-throws-error) but i don't think it is an issue with the namespace as it's internal function, not a user function, that is giving me the problem.

i'm using dompdf in my php application and the following function within their dompdf classes is causing me problems....

```
if ( !function_exists('sys_get_temp_dir')) {
    /**
     * Find the current system temporary directory
     *
     * @link http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php#85261
     */
    function sys_get_temp_dir() {
        if (!empty($_ENV['TMP'])) { return realpath($_ENV['TMP']); }
        if (!empty($_ENV['TMPDIR'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TMPDIR']); }
        if (!empty($_ENV['TEMP'])) { return realpath( $_ENV['TEMP']); }
        $tempfile=tempnam(uniqid(rand(),TRUE),'');
        if (file_exists($tempfile)) {
        unlink($tempfile);
        return realpath(dirname($tempfile));
        }
    }
}
```

and there i'm getting is

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare sys_get_temp_dir() on line 873
```

when i echo out using the get_defined_functions() method it shows the function sys_get_temp_dir towards the end of the list so it shouldn't even be getting into the if statement i wouldn't have thought??

Comment: Is line 873 the function declaration shown above? And you should never use more than one question mark.

Comment: yeah function sys_get_temp_dir() is line 873

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question but, since this function is actually defined in the version of PHP you are running, you could just delete this entire block of code. If you only care about getting your app to work, that should do it.

Comment: interesting... commenting out the code brings another error which might be why this is happening in the first place:

Warning: sys_get_temp_dir() has been disabled for security reasons

on the following line:

def("DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR", sys_get_temp_dir());

i've just commented that and away we go... cheers!

Comment: FYI, you'll need the temp directory for image processing and URL file access. You can define the temp directory manually. It's recommended that you modify your configuration using dompdf_config.custom.inc.php. Modify the relevant line to read something like `define('DOMPDF_TEMP_DIR','/path/to/writeable/directory');`.

Comment: You might also want to see what else is disabled on your system. I wouldn't be surprised if allow_url_fopen was set to false, which would disable URL access to files.

Answer (score 1):

For people that do not wish to dig through the comments:

If a function is disabled via the php.ini file, namely by naming in the `disable_functions` directive, the `function_exists` function will return `false`, but redeclaring the function is still not allowed. Simply remove the function from the `disable_functions` list and the code will work as expected.

You can check if this is the problem for you by running `phpinfo()` on a test page, or by running the function on a test page and looking at the error log. Actually running the function will put a message in the error log that the function has been disabled for security reasons.